# AWS CodeBuild directory issues?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

Using the stock CodeBuild Ubuntu14.04 base image.

Anyone else experiencing odd behavior with directories? Commands like "pushd" do not exist. You start out in this weird "/tmp/src200838814/src" directory. The cd command seems wonky too.

Really hard when you are trying to run cmake.

Answer (score 8):

The way AWS CodeBuild works is that each command is executed in the base directory. For your case all commands will be executed in "/tmp/src200838814/src". If you would like to execute commands in a different directory you will have to chain a single command to move you then execute for example.

```
cd other-dir && cmake
```

Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Something was funky with cd. I had to tell cmake the source and target paths instead as changing into the build directory was not working. Also funky business with swap space being impermissible to mount.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this env CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR?

I always cd to this one before executing anything to make sure I know what is my current directory.

```
cd ${CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR}
```